# Akka ActorSystem Control

Tags: scala, network-programming, playframework-2.0, akka, actor

my environment is scala akka and the play! framework. I was wondering if there is anyway to control the creation of an actor system or any other ideas that can .

My idea is to create remote actors that will handle authorization when a user hits buy. And so, I create the remote actor system and actors in an action method, when a user does a post:

```
def payment = Action { implicit request =>
  var actorObject: Array[String] = new Array[String](23)

  val system = ActorSystem("RemoteSystem", ConfigFactory.load.getConfig("remotecreation")

  val worker = system.actorOf(Props[authNetActor.AuthNetActorMain].withRouter(FromConfig()), name = "remoteActor")
  ...
  system.shutdown()
}
```

Here is the definition of remotecreation in the application.conf

```
remotecreation {        #user defined name for the configuration
    include "common"
    akka {
            actor {
                    serialize-messages = on
                    serialize-creators = on

                    serializers {
                            proto = "akka.serialization.ProtobufSerializer"
                            java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
                            arr = "models.ArraySerializer"
                    }

                    serialization-bindings {
                            "com.google.protobuf.Message" = proto
                            "java.lang.String" = java
                            "java.util.Arrays" = java
                            "scala.Array" = arr
                            "akka.actor.ActorRef" = java
                    }

                    deployment {
                            /remoteActor {  #Specifically has to be the name of the remote actor
                                    remote = "akka://ActorApplication@172.17.100.232:2552"
                                    router = "round-robin"
                                    nr-of-instances = 1
                            }
                    }
            }
            remote.netty.port = 2554
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that, when I submit twice in a row, I get an error because I am trying to create an actor system on an ip address that already has an actor system on it.

I definitely think I need to move it, but I'm not sure where because since this is going to be a wide, multi user play! application, I'm not sure where I can put the creation of the actor system without being conflicted when hundreds of users use the application.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Don't start a (remote) ActorSystem per call. Instead, start up an application-wide actor system (or use the default one, see [integrating Play with Akka](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka)).

Add to your `application.conf`:

```
akka {

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0 # 2552 seems to be bound with play 2.0.2 ?
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the default Play actorsystem for example to get a reference to the remote actor in your contorller:

```
private val interpreters = Akka.system.actorFor(
  "akka://interpreter_system@127.0.0.1:2552/user/interpreters")
```

You might even convert an Akka Future to a Scala Promise if you want to render the actor response. I avice to keep using Akka Futures for composability, then at the very last stem convert the `Future[Result]` to a Promise.

```
new AkkaPromise(
  interpreters.ask(InterpretersComm.Request(sid, line)).mapTo[String]) map (Ok(_))
```

Comment: The examples are from a toy project of mine using remote scala interpreters.